# How to compute julian arithmetic

Tags: c++, math, julian-date

I have problem where I need to find the difference between a 18-digit current julian-timestamp and a constant amount of minutes and the result should be a 18-digit julian timestamp again.

Now I have the lib provided api to get the 18-digit current julian-timestamp, but I am not able to find a simple way to compute the rest.

```
J = 18-digit current julian-timestamp; /* this I have */
M = an integer, which indicates the number of minutes elapsed.

J-M = R is a 18-digit julian-timestamp
```

Please suggest an simplified way to compute R.

Comment: Also, what does `J-M = R` mean? Is just a typo, and you really meant `R = J + M`, or is it anything else?

Comment: My bad, I should have written 'simple' instead of optimized. I don't need optimized way in terms of performance but I need less number of statements.

Comment: No I need J+M only, Btw +/- anything is fine

Comment: Time arithmetic is not this easy. You have to deal with leap years, leap days, and leap seconds.

Comment: But what is a 18 digits Julian timestamp ? AFAIK a Julian date is simply a continuous count of days and fractions since noon Universal Time on January 1, 4713 BCE (on the proleptic Julian calendar). I know how to do calculations on Julian days, add them any number of days, minutes or seconds, convert them to and from current gregorian calendar, but I **do not know what is a 18 digits Julian timestamp**

Comment: @Yay295 : that's the reason why the Julian day was invented :-) and julian date does not deal with leap seconds.

Comment: @SergeBallesta some interpretations of Julian day include leap seconds, but the leap second is confined to the day in which it occurs. In that particular day, a second represents the fraction 1/86401 of a day, instead of the usual 1/86400. This is done in the Standards of Fundamental Astronomy software libraries.

Answer (score 2):

The common usage is to store Julian dates in a double. According to [Julian day on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day), Julian day for January 1, 2000 12:00 UT is 2,451,545. So we need about 7 decimal digits do process the day. Since a double has a precision of about 13 decimal digits, we are still left with 6 decimal digits for the fraction of a day. As a day contains 86400 seconds, a Julian day contained in a float can represent all dates since noon on January 1, 4713 BC, in proleptic Julian calendar with a precision of at least one second.

And as the Julian Period (same reference) is *a chronological interval of 7980 years beginning 4713 BC, it can still represent about 2000 years starting from now.

So you should just convert your timestamp to a double, add it `(double) M / 1440.` and you get the new Julian timestamp.

If you later want to convert a Julian day in our Gregorian calendar you just have to use the difference with January 1, 2000 12:00 UT which is 2,451,545

Answer (score 0):

I will suppose paper plane's question, combined with paper plane's comment at 22 July, 15:55Z, is correct. I endorse Serge Ballesta's comment about the definition of a Julian date.

J = Julian date, for example, it is currently 2457226.38645800000. Neither a double float nor a long integer can hold that many digits, so I suppose this must be a character string.

M = integer indicating a number of minutes to be added to J.

Your first task is to figure out how precise your result must be, and what range of dates you must cover. If you don't require precision better than a few microseconds, you could separate J into two integers, the whole number part and the fraction part. Then convert the number of minutes into days by dividing M by 1440. Then add the result to the fraction part of J. Next, handle any carry that might happen between the fraction part and the whole number part. Then assign to a string the whole number part, the decimal point, the fraction part, and right-pad with enough digits to make 18 digits alltogether.

Comment: A double should be more than adequate to contain the date! Those suckers are good for 53 digits https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/zMachine.html

Comment: Correction: wow, what an accurate number number .. doubles are good for 53 _binary_ digits - check out the Rmpfr library for that sort of precision

Comment: Thanks @Gerand, Since M is in minute so it should be divided by 1440 to get the number of days, isn't it? I suppose 86400 was a typo. I am not familiar with Julian arithmetic, please let me know if it is otherwise.

Comment: Yes, 86400 was a typo. It should be 1440. I'll edit the answer for any future readers.